# Python CS GO Case Simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, simulation

I'm a beginner in Python, 1-2 months experience. Please assess my code. I used a dictionary to store cases. The cases_data is stored in another file. Is the structuring right? My code seems to have a lot of whitespace, how can I restructure it for readability? The code runs successfully as intended, but is the code suited for maintainability (adding new features)? Am I following the Python standard? Is this satisfactory for industrial standard? I did this project for leisure.

```
cases = {
"wildfire" : {
    "blue" : ['Tec-9 | Jambiya', 'USP-S | Lead Conduit', 'SSG 08 | Necropos', 'Dual Berettas | Cartel', 'MAC-10 | Lapis Gator', 'PP-Bizon | Photic Zone'],
    "purple" : ['MAG-7 | Praetorian', 'FAMAS | Valence', 'Five-SeveN | Triumvirate', 'Glock-18 | Royal Legion'],
    "pink" : ['Desert Eagle | Kumicho Dragon', 'Nova | Hyper Beast', 'AWP | Elite Build'],
    "red" : ['AK-47 | Fuel Injector', 'M4A4 | The Battlestar'],
    },
"chroma 2" : {
    'blue' : ['AK-47 | Elite Build', 'MP7 | Armor Core', 'Desert Eagle | Bronze Deco', 'P250 | Valence', 'Sawed-Off | Origami'],
    'purple' : ['AWP | Worm God', 'MAG-7 | Heat', 'CZ75-Auto | Pole Position', 'UMP-45 | Grand Prix'],
    'pink' : ['Five-SeveN | Monkey Business', 'Galil AR | Eco', 'FAMAS | Dijinn'],
    'red' : ['M4A1-S | Hyper Beast', 'MAC-10 | Neon Rider'],
    },
}


import random
from cases_data import *

stattrrak=['StatTrrak',]
knives=['Karambit', 'Flip knife', 'M9 Bayonet', 'Bayonet', 'Flachion', 'Shaddow Daggers', 'Bowie Knife']
wear = ['battle scarred', 'well worn', 'field tested', 'minimal wear', 'factory new']


print ("Hello! Welcome to CS GO case lottery!")
print ("Available cases: Wildfire and Chroma 2")
print ("Winning a purple skin gives you 1 additional key!")
print ("Winning a pink skin gives you 3 additional keys!")
print ("Winning a red skin gives you 7 additional keys!")
print ("Winning a knife gives you 15 additional keys!")

global caseKeys
caseKeys = 1
def skin_wear():
    x = random.choice(wear)
    return x
def case_run():
    global caseKeys
    chance1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    while caseKeys >0:
        resp = input("Which case would you like to open? ")
        for i in cases:
            if resp.lower() == i:
                caseKeys -= 1
                colours = list(cases[i].items())

                #print ("Colours: %s" % colours)
                chance = random.randint(1, 100)
                for x, y in enumerate([25, 10, 5, 2]):
                    if chance >=y:
                        trakChance= random.randint(1, 100)
                        skinRarity = colours[x][0]
                        skin = random.choice(colours[x][1])
                        if trakChance <= 35:
                            print ("You've won a %s (%s) (%s skin) (StatTrrak)" % (skin, skin_wear(), skinRarity))
                            print ("With a chance of %s" % chance)

                        else:
                            print ("You've won a %s (%s) (%s skin)" % (skin, skin_wear(), skinRarity))
                            print ("With a chance of %s" % chance)
                        if skinRarity == 'purple':
                            caseKeys += 1
                        elif skinRarity == 'pink':
                            caseKeys += 3
                        elif skinRarity == 'red':
                            caseKeys += 7
                        print ("Keys left: %s" % caseKeys)
                        break                   
                    elif chance == 1:
                        print ("You've won a %s, Congratulations!" % random.choice(knives))
                        print ("With a chance of %s" % chance)
                        print ("Nice! 15 more keys!")
                        caseKeys += 15
                        print ("Keys left: %s" % caseKeys)
                        break
                break

        if resp.lower() != i:
            print ("Please see list for cases")
    else:
        print ("You've run out of keys")




    if caseKeys == 0:
        resp2=input("Would you like to try again? ")
        if resp2.lower() == 'yes' or 'y':
            resp3=int(input("How many keys? "))
            caseKeys = resp3
            case_run()
        else:
            sys.exit()

case_run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Python, language of the whitespace. Second only to whitespace itself. More seriously your code is alright, however I'd recommend you change it a lot to make it better.

- Python has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I recommend that you follow this style guide so that other Python users can more easily read and understand your code.
- Don't use `global`, there normally is a way around using it. In this example there's actually no need for it. Using `global` is a bad habit to get into, and is *heavily* discouraged.
- There's no need for `sys.exit`. Your code will work the same way if you just `return`ed from the function.
- Split up your function. `open_case` should be one of your functions, and a `main` should be another.
- Use [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/__main__.html). This prevents code from running if you `import` it.
- Since you're using `random.choice` on the other attributes of the item, it doesn't make sense to me for `skin_wear` to be on it's own.
- The if else around `if trakChance <= 35:` makes your code wet. Instead you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatstrings).

  ```
  f"{' (StatTrack)' if track_chance <= 35 else ''}"
  ```
- Breaks `break`s everywhere! I'd recommend you [use control flow statements](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html) when needed, but not when they're not. Improper use can lead to confusion, and can make [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).
- You have a bug `resp2.lower() == 'yes' or 'y'` is always `True`. This is as it checks the left hand side of `or`, `resp2.lower() == 'yes'`. If this is true, then it skips checking the right hand side, otherwise it checks the right hand side. So if `resp2` is `n`, then the result of the statement is `y`. Which is truthy.

  Instead use `in` and build a tuple or a set. Such as:

  ```
  if resp2.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
  ```
- Your code requires [an implementation detail on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) to work correctly:

  > The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon

  Instead use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).
- You may want to store your global constants in a file outside of Python. One way to do this is in [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html).

Using most of the above I changed your code to:

```
import random

CASES = {
    "wildfire" : {
        "blue" : ['Tec-9 | Jambiya', 'USP-S | Lead Conduit', 'SSG 08 | Necropos', 'Dual Berettas | Cartel', 'MAC-10 | Lapis Gator', 'PP-Bizon | Photic Zone'],
        "purple" : ['MAG-7 | Praetorian', 'FAMAS | Valence', 'Five-SeveN | Triumvirate', 'Glock-18 | Royal Legion'],
        "pink" : ['Desert Eagle | Kumicho Dragon', 'Nova | Hyper Beast', 'AWP | Elite Build'],
        "red" : ['AK-47 | Fuel Injector', 'M4A4 | The Battlestar'],
        },
    "chroma 2" : {
        'blue' : ['AK-47 | Elite Build', 'MP7 | Armor Core', 'Desert Eagle | Bronze Deco', 'P250 | Valence', 'Sawed-Off | Origami'],
        'purple' : ['AWP | Worm God', 'MAG-7 | Heat', 'CZ75-Auto | Pole Position', 'UMP-45 | Grand Prix'],
        'pink' : ['Five-SeveN | Monkey Business', 'Galil AR | Eco', 'FAMAS | Dijinn'],
        'red' : ['M4A1-S | Hyper Beast', 'MAC-10 | Neon Rider'],
    },
}
KNIVES = ['Karambit', 'Flip knife', 'M9 Bayonet', 'Bayonet', 'Flachion', 'Shaddow Daggers', 'Bowie Knife']
WEAR = ['battle scarred', 'well worn', 'field tested', 'minimal wear', 'factory new']
BONUS_KEYS = {
    'purple': 1,
    'pink': 3
    'red': 7
}


def open_case(case):
    chance = random.randint(1, 100)
    for (rarity, skins), y in zip(list(case.items()), [25, 10, 5, 2]):
        if chance < y:
            continue
        track_chance = random.randint(1, 100)
        skin = random.choice(skins)
        wear = random.choice(WEAR)
        item = f"{skin} ({wear}) ({rarity} skin){' (StatTrack)' if track_chance <= 35 else ''}"
        return item, chance, BONUS_KEYS.get(rarity, 0)
    return random.choice(KNIVES), chance, 15


def case_run(keys):
    while keys:
        resp = input("Which case would you like to open? ")
        try:
            case = CASES[resp.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            print ("Please see list for cases")
            continue
        else:
            item, chance, bonus_keys = open_case(case)
            print(f"You've won a {item}")
            print(f"With a chance of {chance}")
            if bonus_keys:
                print(f"Nice! {bonus_keys} more keys!")
            keys += bonus_keys - 1
            print(f"Keys left: {keys}")
    else:
        print ("You've run out of keys")

def main():
    keys = 1
    while True:
        case_run(keys)

        resp = input("Would you like to try again? ")
        if resp.lower() in ('yes', 'y'):
            keys = int(input("How many keys? "))
        else:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Hello! Welcome to CS GO case lottery!")
    print ("Available cases: Wildfire and Chroma 2")
    print ("Winning a purple skin gives you 1 additional key!")
    print ("Winning a pink skin gives you 3 additional keys!")
    print ("Winning a red skin gives you 7 additional keys!")
    print ("Winning a knife gives you 15 additional keys!")

    main()
```

Comment: Clear and understandable, thank you. This project burnt half of my brain.